# react-table and react-window column width behavior

Tags: react-table, react-window

I am making a virtualized table using react-table and react-window. Without using virtualization, the columns in the table are displayed evenly, the total width is normally calculated and so on. But with virtualized list I can't get the same result. Does anyone have any experience using these libraries in this case?

With virtualizarion [image]

With normal table
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the exact same problem, ended up using CSS to customize each width on each column in the header and then on the rows.

Comment: The problem is that this table is used in many places in the application and it is convenient to throw in the width, maxWidth, minWidth, and this way I will probably get a table specifically for one case :(